# For creating custom list view as a library in android

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-controls, android-custom-view, android-2.3-gingerbread

we want to create a **list view** using adapter and we want to set the properties of the the list item outside the adapter.

For instance ,the list view contains **200 rows and 14 column,** then we need to create the list item using adapter.Here the objects in adapter is creating based on the which items shown in screen.

After creating adapter ,after outside adapter we want to put getter,setter for the item 198 means .If initially in device the items upto 10 is diplayed means then then 10 items objects is created in adapter but the remaining is created when user scroll down

So null pointer execption is arised for the item 198.

I want to create a ListView as a custom component.In that the user can add any number of rows,any number of columns,etc

Any items as a list view,etc.

My aim is to create **library for list view** .In that list view user can add any number of rows,any number of columns,any items textview,spinner,etc.I need suggestions how to achieve it

All are welcome to give their ideas.

Comment: Please post your code. And what does this have to do with android-2.3?

Comment: do you want to implement some library or code from native to make a library project?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to implement [LazyListView](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).

And I think you have a nice [tutorial here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/23/simplest-lazy-loading-listview-android-data-populated-mysql-database-php/) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

try use:
your xml list file item.xml:

```
<LinearLayout>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/cbBox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</CheckBox>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvDescr"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:text=""
android:textSize="20sp">
</TextView>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:text="">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ivImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher">
</ImageView>
<LinearLayout/>
```

And your class adapter

```
public class BoxAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Product> objects;

BoxAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> products) {
ctx = context;
objects = products;
lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View view = convertView;
if (view == null) {
view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
}

Product p = getProduct(position);
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescr)).setText(p.name);
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice)).setText(p.price + "");
((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage)).setImageResource(p.image);

CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cbBox);
cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
cbBuy.setTag(position);
cbBuy.setChecked(p.box);
return view;
}

Product getProduct(int position) {
return ((Product) getItem(position));
}

ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
ArrayList<Product> box = new ArrayList<Product>();
for (Product p : objects) {
if (p.box)
box.add(p);
}
return box;
}

OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangList = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
    boolean isChecked) {
 getProduct((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).box = isChecked;
}
}; 
}
```

And your class for product

```
public class Product {
String name;
int price;
int image;
boolean box;

Product(String _describe, int _price, int _image, boolean _box) {
name = _describe;
price = _price;
image = _image;
box = _box;
}
}
```

And your main activity use the create adapter

```
boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, products);
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
...
//create adapter
fillData()
boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(this, products);

// use lists
ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
}

// data for adapter
void fillData() {
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
products.add(new Product("Product " + i, i * 1000, R.drawable.ic_launcher, false));
}
```

Comment: ZHARIK86 ur explaination is very usefull to me.But my aim is to create library for  list view .In that list view user can add any number of rows,any number of columns,any items textview,spinner,etc.Give your suggestions how to achieve it

Comment: SIVAKUMAR.J, as far as I understood the task, it is necessary to make for example so. If you want that the user defined appearance of the list, for example, it is possible to create at first a look by default and to use it as LayoutInflater. Further we do somewhere the button on which we bind events of opening of AlertDialog (or, FrameDialog as it is more convenient). In this dialog we show our original placement and falling out by the list we do adding of other elements.

Comment: SIVAKUMAR.J, it is necessary not to forget about deleting elements which don't suit us. After the user decided on a set, we its storage, using getWindow (). Remaining operation is similar to that is already given above.